SonarQube Still Showing Blocker Bug on Dashboard After Fix Has Been Applied
I’m facing an issue with SonarQube where a blocker bug is still reported on the dashboard for a branch I'm working on, even though the issue has been fixed in the code and it works fine in my local environment.
The issue was originally flagged by SonarQube as:
"Use try-with-resources or close this ExecutorService in a finally clause."
I refactored the code to ensure that the ExecutorService is properly shutdown in the finally block, using a utility method to handle the shutdown sequence. This works locally, and SonarQube no longer flags it when I analyze it on my local machine.
The updated code has been pushed to the branch I am collaborating on, and I can confirm that the new code is present in the repository. However, the SonarQube dashboard for the branch still shows the same blocker issue, even after the fix is applied.
What I've Tried:

Re-running the SonarQube analysis on my local machine, which no
longer shows the issue.
Verifying that the updated code has been
successfully pushed to the branch.
Checking the SonarQube project
settings to ensure there are no discrepancies in the analysis
configuration between my local environment and the branch analysis (also tried to delete the whole project and recreate it).

Why might SonarQube still be reporting this issue on the team branch dashboard, even though the fix has been applied and the code is up-to-date? Is there something I’m missing in the branch analysis process or SonarQube settings?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

Did you check in the logs if SonarQube pulls the hash which has the commit of your fix ?

@драган-јованковић I can already see the current code on the dashboard and yes it’s updated

did you try cleaning the SonarQube cache ?

@драган-јованковић yes I also deleted the SonarQube project and re-created it again
